# connecting to multiple instances of EC2 with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I just started out with Amazon web services and was able to launch an instance. A friend showed me a sample tutorial of how to connect to AWS with ssh. Pretty neat. I downloaded the key and edited /.ssh/config file. 
Sample of the config file

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 300

Host <name desired to connect>
 HostName <domain name>
 port 22
 User ubuntu
 IdentityFile /pathname/keyfile
```

My question is what if i have 2 instances and now i want to ssh to the new instance launched. How will i edit the config file. I'm stuck and also new to Linux(been learning Linux yesterday and it's pretty cool and powerful). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ssh to any ec2 instance by running this on terminal:

```
ssh -i path_to_pem_file ubuntu@<HostIP_or_NAME>
```

eg.

```
ssh -i /temp/root1.pem ubuntu@54.23.122.34
```